# Getting SQL Syntax Error when loading schema.sql file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I have a pretty basic schema.sql file:

Ideally, I just want the tables to auto-generate. I've disabled the auto ddl setting in my `application.properties`. However, I am getting errors:

## Error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/schachte/Documents/Habicus-Core/build/resources/main/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE `goal_metrics` (; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ""GOAL_METRICS"" ( [*]"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:

## Schema.SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `goal_metrics` (
  `goal_metrics_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `goal_complete` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goal_in_progress` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `money_made_on_goal` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_until_due_date` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `goals_goal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`goal_metrics_id`,`goals_goal_id`),
  KEY `fk_goal_metrics_goals1_idx` (`goals_goal_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_goal_metrics_goals1` FOREIGN KEY (`goals_goal_id`) REFERENCES `goals` (`goal_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `metrics` (
  `goalsInProgress` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`goalsInProgress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dob` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You seem to be using MySQL syntax, but your error message indicates you're using h2. h2 is not mysql. I doubt h2 recognizes MySQL syntax such as back-ticks for identifier delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, only to realise that h2db doesn't like it when you use **reserved words**. Don't name your DB or Tables or even fields using reserved words like:

- Group
- Memory
- Select
- Authorization

...etc...

I solved it by renaming my Domain Objects (& made sure that non of the names match the **reserved h2db names**), since I'm using Spring JPA, Repositories.

A common mistake most people make, is to use MySql Syntax on H2DB. Refrain from making that mistake too. H2 Database has its own syntax.